# Моментальна перезапись <input> в js

Tags: javascript, input

Вчера сломался на казалось такой элементарной задаче.

Мне нужен input куда влезает всего один символ,
каждый последующий символ будет перезаписывать старый.

Вот что я написал:

```
 input.addEventListener('input', () => {
      if (input.value.length > 1) input.value = ''
    })
```

У меня выходит лишний шаг: 1)Ввел символ -> 2)Удалил старый -> 3)Ввел новый.


А нужно: 1)Ввел символ -> 2)Одновременно удалил старый и ввел новый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обработчик, в качестве аргумента, передается объект с информацией о введенном символе (свойство `data`). Просто заменяем значение input:

```js
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  input.value = e.data;
});
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

Comment: И снова встретились)

Comment: и еще я опять невнимательно прочитал вопрос)))

Comment: @МихаилРебров Торопиться не следует, конечно ))

Comment: оставлю вам вопрос)